# How can I add a drop-down menu to change the theme of sci chart using html and js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scichart.js

I have an XY SciChart.js chart in which I added two line charts with dummy data.

[image]

Then I added a drop-down menu.

**How can I add a drop-down menu to change the theme of sci chart** using **html** **css** and **js** in visual studio code?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In future suggest using the Code button to insert code samples not a screenshot of VS Code. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow for instructions

Answer (score 1):

You can update the theme for a sciChartSurface by calling sciChartSurface.applyTheme.  Documentation for this is [here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/webframe.html#Chart%20Styling%20-%20ThemeManager%20API.html)

If your select has the id "theme":

```
document.querySelector("#theme").onchange = (ev) => {
  const value = ev.target.value;
  let theme = new SciChart.SciChartJSDarkv2Theme();
  if (value === "Light") {
    theme = new SciChart.SciChartJSLightTheme();
  } else if  (value === "Custom") {
    theme.lineSeriesColor = "red";
    theme.sciChartBackground = `radial-gradient(circle, #615EFF 0%, #C4DFFF 100%)`;
    theme.axisBandsFill = "#AACDFF33";
    theme.tickTextBrush = "#0C0C63";
   }
  sciChartSurface.applyTheme(theme);
}
```

[Full example on codepen](https://codepen.io/scichart/pen/MWBGjaL)